JPQL did not translated to SQL correctly when using Window Functions
Models:
@Entity
@Data
//This is main entity
public class Collection {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
 
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "belongsTo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @OrderBy("id desc")
  private List<Vocabulary> vocabularies;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "collection")
  private List<CollectionAccess> collectionAccesses;

  @CreatedDate protected LocalDateTime createdAtUtc;
  @CreatedBy protected UUID createdBy;
  @LastModifiedDate protected LocalDateTime lastModifiedAtUtc;
  @LastModifiedBy protected UUID lastModifiedBy;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Vocabulary {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  //Other fields
  
}

@Entity
@Data
public class CollectionAccess {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private Integer accessType; //1 means public
  private LocalDateTime expirationAtUtc;

  //Other field
}

Our goal: Find Collection(s) that:

Have a name (0)
Belongs to current-logged-in User (via createdBy) (1)
OR have been published via CollectionAccess (if a Collection contains at least ONE CollectionAccess which has accessType==1, mean this Collection has been published) (2)
Join fetch Vocabulary to avoid N + 1 issue (3)
Paging is required (4)

Since there is/are join fetch here, so Hibernate will do limit/offset in memory. To avoid that, a tweak need to be done using Window Function (see this)
Our JPQL:
SELECT c FROM Collection c 
  LEFT JOIN FETCH c.vocabularies v --(3)
WHERE c.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT 
          cc.id AS id, 
          dense_rank() over (
            order by 
              id asc
          ) AS ranking 
        FROM Collection cc 
        WHERE 
          UPPER(name) LIKE ?1 --(0)
          AND (
            createdBy = ?2 --(1)
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 FROM CollectionAccess ca 
              WHERE ca.collection.id = id 
                AND ca.accessType = : accessType --(2)
                AND ca.expirationAtUtc <= : expirationAtUtc --just check expiration
            )
          )
      ) pr 
    WHERE 
      ranking >= : offset 
      AND ranking <= : until --(4)
  ) 
order by 
  c.id asc

This JPQL can run, but did not return anything, and I found out the reason.
This is native SQL generated by Hibernate:
    select
        c1_0.id,
        c1_0.created_at_utc,
        c1_0.created_by,
        c1_0.description,
        c1_0.image_id,
        c1_0.image_name,
        c1_0.image_url,
        c1_0.language,
        c1_0.last_modified_at_utc,
        c1_0.last_modified_by,
        c1_0.name,
        c1_0.owner_id,
        c1_0.persistable_status,
        v1_0.collection_id,
        v1_0.id,
        v1_0.created_at_utc,
        v1_0.created_by,
        v1_0.last_modified_at_utc,
        v1_0.last_modified_by,
        v1_0.owner_id,
        v1_0.persistable_status,
        v1_0.vocabulary 
    from
        collection c1_0 
    left join
        vocabulary v1_0 
            on c1_0.id=v1_0.collection_id 
    where
        c1_0.id in (select
            pr1_0.id 
        from
            (select
                c2_0.id id, dense_rank() over(
            order by
                c2_0.id) ranking 
            from
                collection c2_0 
            where
                upper(c2_0.name) like replace(?, '\\', '\\\\') 
                and (c2_0.created_by=? 
                or exists(select
                    1 id 
                from
                    collection_access ca1_0 
                where
                    ca1_0.collection_id=ca1_0.id --WRONG HERE
                    and ca1_0.access_type=? 
                    and ca1_0.expiration_at_utc<=?))) pr1_0 
        where
            pr1_0.ranking>=? 
            and pr1_0.ranking<=?) 
    order by
        c1_0.id,
        v1_0.id desc

The where ca1_0.collection_id=ca1_0.id is WRONG. It should be where ca1_0.collection_id=c2_0.id or just where ca1_0.collection_id=id
We also tried some small tweak and hope that Hibernate would generate correct SQL:
SELECT c FROM Collection c 
  LEFT JOIN FETCH c.vocabularies v 
WHERE c.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT 
          cc.id AS id, 
          dense_rank() over (
            order by 
              id asc
          ) AS ranking 
        FROM Collection cc 
        WHERE 
          UPPER(name) LIKE ?1 
          AND (
            createdBy = ?2 
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 FROM CollectionAccess ca 
              WHERE 
                ca.collection.id = cc.id --FIX HERE: change ca.collection.id = id to ca.collection.id = cc.id
                AND ca.accessType = : accessType 
                AND ca.expirationAtUtc <= : expirationAtUtc
            )
          )
      ) pr 
    WHERE 
      ranking >= : offset 
      AND ranking <= : until
  ) 
order by 
  c.id asc

But we got an error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret path expression 'cc.id'
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer$BaseLocalSequencePart.resolvePathPart(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.consumeIdentifier(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimplePath(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:5060) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitIndexedPathAccessFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:5009) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4984) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1776) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$GeneralPathExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:7699) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:46) ~[antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar:4.13.0]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParserBaseVisitor.visitBarePrimaryExpression(HqlParserBaseVisitor.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$BarePrimaryExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:7157) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.createComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2430) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2392) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$ComparisonPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6164) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2261) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$AndPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6039) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2261) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$AndPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6039) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2244) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5905) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1159) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:941) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1869) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:926) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1740) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSubquery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4931) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSubqueryExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4911) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSubqueryExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SubqueryExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:7326) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitExistsPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitExistsPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$ExistsPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6015) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitOrPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2271) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitOrPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$OrPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6255) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGroupedPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2252) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGroupedPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$GroupedPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6084) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2262) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$AndPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6039) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2244) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5905) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1159) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:941) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1869) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:926) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1740) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:402) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.interpretHql(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:790) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionImpl.createReactiveQuery(ReactiveSessionImpl.java:368) ~[hibernate-reactive-core-2.2.2.Final.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.reactive.stage.impl.StageSessionImpl.createQuery(StageSessionImpl.java:517) ~[hibernate-reactive-core-2.2.2.Final.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at com.htech.vocab.repository.impl.CollectionRepositoryCustomImpl.getSelectionQuery(CollectionRepositoryCustomImpl.java:240) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htech.vocab.repository.impl.CollectionRepositoryCustomImpl.buildQueryAndExecute(CollectionRepositoryCustomImpl.java:281) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htech.vocab.repository.impl.CollectionRepositoryCustomImpl.lambda$findAllOwnedOrPublicIncludingAllMany$7(CollectionRepositoryCustomImpl.java:146) ~[classes/:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:297) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:478) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:470) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:633) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:633) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:633) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:633) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:633) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:633) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:633) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:633) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.request(MonoZip.java:220) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.request(FluxUsingWhen.java:320) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]


Is it a bug or just an unsupported feature?

Hibernate's support for window functions is fairly new, and there could be bugs.  I seem to recall that the CTE implementation does in fact have some known bugs.  For the time being, just use a native query until you fix the root problem here.
